# 3-point moving average in R

Tags: r, time-series, moving-average

I have some data in the form of a single list of numbers. I want to compute 3-points moving average using the formula in R:

```
(-1a + 2b + -4c)/3 <- 1st moving average
```

where a, b, and c are the 1st, 2nd and 3rd values and so on. The next average would be:

```
(-1b + 2c + -4d)/3 <- 2nd moving average
```

where d is the 4th value.
Someone told me to use the filter() function but I'm not so sure how. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: `stats::filter(vec, c(-1,2,-4)/3)`

Answer (score 1):

You should do:

```
vec <- seq(10)
stats::filter(vec, c(-4,2,-1)/3)
```

or even:

```
c(embed(vec, 3) %*% c(-4,2,-1)/3)
```

Note that in both cases, I reversed the order of the parameters. ie instead of `-1,2,-4` I have `-4,2,-1`. Take note of that